# NHibernate Mapping By Code Cascade All-Delete-Orphans

Tags: nhibernate, cascade, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

How to set cascade to all-delete-orphans with mapping by code in NHibernate?

```
[Flags]
public enum Cascade
{
    None = 0,
    Persist = 2,
    Refresh = 4,
    Merge = 8,
    Remove = 16,
    Detach = 32,
    ReAttach = 64,
    DeleteOrphans = 128,
    All = 256,
}
```

How can I combine All & DeleteOrphans?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use:

```
r.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
```

Because the Cascade is a [Flag] ... multi could be used:

[What does the [Flags] Enum Attribute mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8447/1679310)